# uploading images and call images/alt/title in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, image, content-management-system

im very new to wordpress and coding side.

i want to upload set of images and call those images in a php file.

what im trying to do is creating a slider. i want to upload 5 slider images and add them between src="" using a php code. so when ever user change/delete/add new image, the slider will change.

heres what i want (cant explain it better :( )

backend
http://oi60.tinypic.com/98srpc.jpg

code
http://oi59.tinypic.com/2e1cchi.jpg

please help me friends

thanks

Comment: where did you add this custom fields ?

Comment: i did not add any custom fields.these images i made so i can explain better. (basically i need something like these images)

Comment: do you use any plugins for that?